# Who knows a payment slab for ethereum similar to bitpay?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

It is necessary that the contract would accept payments in different currencies (usd eur etc.) and then pull out tokens. Can this be done as a payment gateway? How is this best done?

Comment: the contract accept only ethers